# Add/Remove dynamic rows and perform calculation using javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a page in mvc 4 that will create dynamic rows and remove rows .. and perform multiplication of quantity and price on change event and addition of total amount using jquery/javascript in mvc 3 / mvc 4. and store values in database.. if anyone can help .. thank you

Comment: You have to put in some effort before you are posting on SO. Read SO Guidelines before you start. Showing some of code that you attempted to solve your problem is the only way you can expect an answer from SO.

Comment: put your effort in your question that I have tried this or some link etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Knkockut.js just like in this [example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html). 
As for data layer you could use entity framework.

Here is some [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amar/archive/2012/12/12/hello-world-with-knockout-js-and-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx) (on Amar's blog)

Comment: how i send this data to database...

Comment: You could use AJAX post, in the tutorial it is done in method `self.addCustomer` (on client side). It sends request to api controller on server side, where method: `public HttpResponseMessage Post(Customer value)` is called. This method performs insert operation on database (via Entioty Framework)